# Minimum Charging requirements for an iPhone

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I am making a thermoelectric charger, which uses heat to charge a phone (with a Peltier module) I use a 0.9v - 5v DC-DC booster and it can charge a Samsung. But when I plug it into an iPhone, it sometimes shows "Unlock iPhone to use accessories" and doesn't charge. Other times it doesn't even show anything.

I am testing it on an iPhone 7 and XS. Both didn't work but a Samsung S7 and a power bank charged.
What are the requirements for charging an iPhone and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: How much voltage and current is actually passing through the charger? The minimum output any of Apple's iPhone chargers have provided is 5V at 1A, so that'd be what I'd be aiming for.

Comment: I'm not too sure about current but the voltage is 5V, I will check the current.